# Unexpected identifier and indentation problems

Tags: f#

I am having some probelems with the code starting with the let enviroment.  The spacing seems to be off and no matter how I fix it still seems to throw errors.  The enviroment line is also giving me an error its not finished

```
let evaluate exp =
let binaryEval = function
    | Add -> ( + )
    | Sub -> ( - )
    | Mul -> ( * )
    | Div -> ( / )
    | Mod -> ( % )
    | Pow -> (fun a b -> a ** (bigIntToInt b))
    // (**) is a comment and ( ** ) represents a function that needs an int, not a bigInt as second arg

let unaryEval = function
    | Factorial,x -> factorial x
    | UMinus,x -> BigInteger.Negate x

let funEval = function 
    | ("sqrt", x:value) -> new value(System.Math.Sqrt(double x))
    | ("abs", x) -> bigint.Abs(x)
    | ("!", x:value) -> unaryEval(Factorial, x)
    | _ -> failwith "Unknown function"

let environment = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, value>()
    environment.["x"] <- 2I
    environment.["y"] <- 3I    
    let lookup name =
        if environment.ContainsKey(name) then
           environment.[name]
        else
            failwith "Invalid variable name"           

let rec eval = function
    | BinaryOp(expr1, op, expr2) -> (binaryEval op) (eval expr1) (eval expr2)
    | Var str -> lookup str
    | UnaryOp(op, expr) -> unaryEval(op,(eval expr))
    | Num d -> d
    | Fun(funName, x::_) -> (funName,(eval x)) |> funEval
    | Fun(_,_) -> failwith "Unknown function"

eval exp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the lines following environment that are the problem - the `let` binding is already finished, but they're indented for no reason. You want to have this (in an fsx you can drop the `do`, but you need to unindent those lines):

```
let environment = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, value>()

do 
   environment.["x"] <- 2I
   environment.["y"] <- 3I    

let lookup name =
    if environment.ContainsKey(name) then
       environment.[name]
    else
        failwith "Invalid variable name"
```

Or perhaps this:

```
let environment, lookup = 
    let environment = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, value>()

    environment.["x"] <- 2I
    environment.["y"] <- 3I    

    let lookup name =
        if environment.ContainsKey(name) then
           environment.[name]
        else
            failwith "Invalid variable name"    

    environment, lookup
```

Also everything under `let evaluate` needs to be indented one level, but that might just be a mistake while pasting.

Comment: Thank you that top one worked and everything was indented 1 level when posting I just deleted the top part of the code that was irrelevant to the question.  Thank you so much